# How to add data into HTML table throug input(textfields) using javascript in laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, html-table

I have been working in laravel for 2 months.
I have a table in html(also can be bootstrap table) and atleast 3 input(type=text) and also have a button(named add). Now i want to add data into table using these three input.When i press add button the data which is present in inputs will add in table Thanks.
My code is given below

```html
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:1em">
    <div class="row no-gutters" style="margin-top: 3px;">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Item Name"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Unit Price"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Item Quantity"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Add Order</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<table></table>
```

Comment: What did you try? Do you want to insert the data into a database and update the table accordingly? Or just add the data to the table at frontend level?

Comment: Yes i also want to add data into the database @azeós

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]When user submit you shouls handle the inputs and move them to the table.
somthing like this:

```
    <form onsubmit="return addtotable()">
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:1em">
      <div class="row no-gutters" style="margin-top: 3px;">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <input id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Enter Item Name"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <input id="input2" type="text" placeholder="Enter Unit Price"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <input id="input3" type="text" placeholder="Enter Item Quantity"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Add Order</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <table id="tabletoadd"></table>
<script>
function addtotable(){
    tabletoadd.innerHTML="<tr><td>Item Name</td><td>Unit Price</td><td>Item Quantity</td></tr><tr><td>"+input1.value+"</td><td>"+input2.value+"</td><td>"+input3.value+"</td></tr>";
return false;
}
</script>
```